# cap production deploy fails on composer:run install

Tags: composer-php, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a project to our production server, as I've done several times before, but it seems to be failing on the composer:run install step.

I run `cap production deploy:check` and everything is great.
I then run `cap production deploy --trace`, which returns the following error when it reaches the composer:run step:

```
>** Invoke deploy:updated (first_time)
>** Invoke composer:install (first_time)
>** Execute composer:install
>** Invoke composer:run (first_time)
>** Execute composer:run
>00:13 composer:run
>      01 composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader
>      01 stdin: is not a tty
>cap aborted!
>SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as xxx@xxxx.xxx: >composer exit status: 1
>composer stdout: Nothing written
>composer stderr: stdin: is not a tty
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in >execute'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
>SSHKit::Command::Failed: composer exit status: 1
>composer stdout: Nothing written
>composer stderr: stdin: is not a tty
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:100:in >`exit_status='
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `execute_command'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in >create_command_and_execute'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:74:in `execute'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-composer->0.0.6/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top >(required)>'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `within'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-composer->0.0.6/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top >(required)>'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
>/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit->1.11.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
>Tasks: TOP => composer:run
>The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as >xxx@xxxx.xxx: composer exit status: 1
>composer stdout: Nothing written
>composer stderr: stdin: is not a tty
>** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
>** Execute deploy:failed
```

I've tried looking up this composer exit status: 1 and it seems to just be a generic error.

I've ssh'd to the production server, and it seems cap is successfully creating a release folder, and pulling the files down from the repo. The error seems to occur when it's installing dependencies.

I'm at a bit of a lose on how to resolve this. Most other threads I've found seemed to have some more informative error messages.

Capistrano log below:

```
INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO START 2016-09-30 09:25:00 -0230 cap production deploy
INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [f3a390e9] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/capistrano_tmp as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [f3a390e9] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/capistrano_tmp )
INFO [f3a390e9] Finished in 2.175 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh 100.0%
INFO [523fe25b] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [523fe25b] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh )
INFO [523fe25b] Finished in 0.125 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [257d5c05] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads $GIT_REPO as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [257d5c05] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads $GIT_REPO )
DEBUG [257d5c05]    a9bd8b177eb5287fa6b968c2a92207c1c25e8bf4    refs/heads/master
INFO [257d5c05] Finished in 6.650 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [63f0ffa5] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/shared /home/USER/public_html/releases as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [63f0ffa5] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/shared /home/USER/public_html/releases )
INFO [63f0ffa5] Finished in 0.124 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [f7a9eb45] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/shared/web/app/uploads as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [f7a9eb45] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/shared/web/app/uploads )
INFO [f7a9eb45] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [ce8a26f9] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/shared as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [ce8a26f9] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/shared )
INFO [ce8a26f9] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [0f2919f9] Running [ -f /home/USER/public_html/shared/.env ] as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [0f2919f9] Command: [ -f /home/USER/public_html/shared/.env ]
DEBUG [0f2919f9] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [0a95dd46] Running [ -f /home/USER/public_html/current/REVISION ] as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [0a95dd46] Command: [ -f /home/USER/public_html/current/REVISION ]
DEBUG [0a95dd46] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [ca7de6e3] Running [ -f /home/USER/public_html/repo/HEAD ] as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [ca7de6e3] Command: [ -f /home/USER/public_html/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [ca7de6e3] Finished in 0.122 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO The repository mirror is at /home/USER/public_html/repo
DEBUG [5efe620a] Running if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [5efe620a] Command: if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [5efe620a] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [b0a1ad08] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [b0a1ad08] Command: cd /home/USER/public_html/repo && ( export WP_ENV="staging" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune )
DEBUG [b0a1ad08]    Fetching origin
INFO [b0a1ad08] Finished in 5.040 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [6d7e14fa] Running if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [6d7e14fa] Command: if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [6d7e14fa] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [0c8f006e] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [0c8f006e] Command: cd /home/USER/public_html/repo && ( export WP_ENV="staging" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 )
INFO [0c8f006e] Finished in 0.125 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [a31715de] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [a31715de] Command: cd /home/USER/public_html/repo && ( export WP_ENV="staging" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 )
INFO [a31715de] Finished in 0.158 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [e57ef477] Running if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [e57ef477] Command: if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [e57ef477] Finished in 0.124 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [cea943e0] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [cea943e0] Command: cd /home/USER/public_html/repo && ( export WP_ENV="staging" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/home/USER/capistrano_tmp/git-ssh-banl-production-MK.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master )
DEBUG [cea943e0]    a9bd8b177eb5287fa6b968c2a92207c1c25e8bf4
DEBUG [cea943e0] Finished in 0.126 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [1759b360] Running if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512'" 1>&2; false; fi as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [1759b360] Command: if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [1759b360] Finished in 0.122 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [ae64693c] Running /usr/bin/env echo "a9bd8b177eb5287fa6b968c2a92207c1c25e8bf4" >> REVISION as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [ae64693c] Command: cd /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 && ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env echo "a9bd8b177eb5287fa6b968c2a92207c1c25e8bf4" >> REVISION )
INFO [ae64693c] Finished in 0.132 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [e9cce54e] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [e9cce54e] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 )
INFO [e9cce54e] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [db1a3471] Running [ -L /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/.env ] as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [db1a3471] Command: [ -L /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/.env ]
DEBUG [db1a3471] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [848e8fe8] Running [ -f /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/.env ] as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [848e8fe8] Command: [ -f /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/.env ]
DEBUG [848e8fe8] Finished in 0.121 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO [7d1f7edd] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/USER/public_html/shared/.env /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/.env as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [7d1f7edd] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/USER/public_html/shared/.env /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/.env )
INFO [7d1f7edd] Finished in 0.122 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [10b70c5d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [10b70c5d] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app )
INFO [10b70c5d] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [880e8bc2] Running [ -L /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads ] as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [880e8bc2] Command: [ -L /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads ]
DEBUG [880e8bc2] Finished in 0.123 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [349e1b98] Running [ -d /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads ] as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [349e1b98] Command: [ -d /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads ]
DEBUG [349e1b98] Finished in 0.121 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [8045d8e0] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [8045d8e0] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads )
INFO [8045d8e0] Finished in 0.125 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [07a69ec8] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/USER/public_html/shared/web/app/uploads /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [07a69ec8] Command: ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/USER/public_html/shared/web/app/uploads /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512/web/app/uploads )
INFO [07a69ec8] Finished in 0.124 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [ca95f29d] Running if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512'" 1>&2; false; fi as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [ca95f29d] Command: if test ! -d /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [ca95f29d] Finished in 0.122 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [ee024dad] Running /usr/bin/env composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader as USER@xxxx.xx
DEBUG [ee024dad] Command: cd /home/USER/public_html/releases/20160930115512 && ( export WP_ENV="staging" ; /usr/bin/env composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader )
```

Comment: Figured out the issue:
One of my plugin dependencies in the composer.json file was causing the install to fail because composer couldn't find the repo.

Running `composer install` AFTER `composer clearcache` revealed the issue. `composer clearcache` is important here because it forces `comopser install` to grab the plugins from their respective repos. Because the plugins were loaded from cache on local dev, so I never saw the error locally.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error message is:

> stdin: is not a tty

This probably means that composer is expecting interactive user input. I am not familiar with composer, but this seems to explain why a non-interactive Capistrano deploy fails but you are able to run the command via an interactive SSH session.

You could try adding this to your Capistrano `deploy.rb`:

```
set :pty, true
```

This tells Capistrano to use a pseudo terminal, which may be enough to make composer happy.

Comment: I tried adding `set :pty, true` to the deploy.rb file, but the error still persists.
I don't think the interaction is the issue though, the composer command that's run is `composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader`, which has a --no-interaction flag.